# How to test the Google Schemas

Tags: email, gmail, google-schemas

I am trying to implement the ParcelDelivery feature for my webshop as shown here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/parcel-delivery

The markup i use validates using this tool:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/

On the help pages it shows that you can test this markup by sending an email from yourself, to yourself. So i am sending myself an email using the GMail web interface, but no matter what i use for the formatting (plain text or html) the "package delivery status" does not show up in my inbox.

Instead, when i click to open the email; the entire code below is shown as the email, just if GMail does not pick it up.

p.s. is this schema also supported in the NOW cards? does anybody know?

Am i doing something wrong?

This is my source used:

```
<html>
  <body>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ParcelDelivery",
  "deliveryAddress": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "name": "John Frank",
    "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
    "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
    "addressRegion": "CA",
    "addressCountry": "US",
    "postalCode": "94107"
  },
  "originAddress": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "name": "John Frank",
    "streetAddress": "25 Willie Mays Plaza",
    "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
    "addressRegion": "CA",
    "addressCountry": "US",
    "postalCode": "94107"
  },
  "expectedArrivalFrom": "2013-03-10T12:00:00-08:00",
  "expectedArrivalUntil": "2013-03-12T12:00:00-08:00",
  "carrier": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "FedEx",
    "url": "http://fedex.com/"
  },
  "itemShipped": {
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "iPod Mini",
    "url": "http://apple.com/ipad32gb",
    "image": "http://apple.com/images/ipad32gb.jpg",
    "sku": "B00DR0PDNE",
    "description": "iPod Mini 32Gb White",
    "brand": {
      "@type": "Brand",
      "name": "Apple"
    },
    "color": "white"
  },
  "trackingNumber": "3453291231",
  "trackingUrl": "http://fedex.com/track/3453291231",
  "hasDeliveryMethod": "http://schema.org/ParcelService",
  "partOfOrder": {
    "@type": "Order",
    "orderNumber": "176057",
    "merchant": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "Bob Dole",
      "sameAs": "http://www.freebase.com/m/0fhkx"
    },
    "orderStatus": "http://schema.org/OrderInTransit"
  }
}
</script>

    <p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
      Order for: John Smith<br/>
      Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
      Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br/>
      Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sending the above JSON-LD as a part of your HTML markup embedded in your email or do you just copy-paste it into the Gmail email compose dialog? If it's the latter, you are doing it wrong, because you're using a WYSIWYG editor and your markup will get treated as text, getting encoded into markup. For instance, `<html>` will get encoded as `&lt;html;&gt;`. You can verify that using the 'Show original' option of Gmail -- what do you see there?

Comment: You should try testing the markup by sending to yourself by doing this Apps script Quick start as shown here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial or you can use this smartmail generator: http://smartmailgenerator.appspot.com/

Comment: @PeterK yes i was indeed sending it inline; makes sense it was being encoded. did not think of that..

KRR The smartmailgenerator keeps redirecting me to my "select account" page; i had success using the script.google.com approach!

Comment: @Gilles: Ok, I guess both of our answers have contributed to solving the problem, so none of us should post it as an answer. Would you mind posting your solution as an answer for future reference?